# How to get HTTP METHOD in http-proxy when proxying a session?

Tags: node.js, proxy, node-http-proxy

I am using Node.js and module `http-proxy` (link [here](https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-proxy)) to proxy requests in my server.

#### Detecting DELETE requests

What I want to achieve is performing certain action when an HTTP DELETE request is sent.

#### Poor doc

How can I do this? Module `http-proxy` comes with a very poor documentation and objects like `res`, `req` and `proxyRes` are not properly documented. From the doc it is possible to understand that object `proxyRes` has a property called `headers` and nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[req.method](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/all.html#all_message_method) is the property you want. It will be a string corresponding to the HTTP request method such as 'DELETE', 'GET', 'POST', etc. node-http-proxy does not document this because it is part of the node core `http.IncomingMessage` standard API (docs linked above).

Comment: So those fields available in methods are actually part of the node.js API? Amazing!!!